# selecting elements from a list with two numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list with numerical and non numerical elements:

`l1={{1,1},{2,2},{a,a},{,b},{c,};`

what is an efficient rule to select the elements where both components are numerical? so I should be able to obtain l2={{1,1},{2,2}}.
thanks

Comment: [35101](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35101/5478)

Comment: indeed, as written in that post:
'Select[l1,AllTrue@NumericQ]' 
does the trick.